# Swashbuckle - How to include parameter types in the Schema section

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have an Azure Function App using Swashbuckle.

```cs
[FunctionName("DoWorkV2")]
[QueryStringParameter("DoWorkParameters", "", DataType = typeof(DoWorkParametersV2), Required = true)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DoWorkResults), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public static async Task<IActionResult> DoWorkV2(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
```

The return type as defined by ProducesResponseType attribute is included in the schema section.
The parameter as defined by QueryStringParameter attribute is not included in the schema section.

How do I make the parameter appear in the schema section so my consumers can know what kind of parameter to pass ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating dummy method using ProducesResponseType for the type contained in the QueryStringParameter. Now I have two extra methods to do nothing. Seems kind of hacky, but the type now appears in the schema section of Swagger page.

```
[FunctionName("DoWorkParametersV2Factory")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DoWorkParametersV2), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public static async Task<IActionResult> DoWorkParametersV2Factory(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
```